# Проблема в отображении кнопки

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Есть кнопка в которую вставлена картинка, я сделал ей FlatStyle=none и BorderSize=0, но у меня при определенных обстоятельствах открывается диалоговое окно в виде команды `(MessageBox::Show("текст");)`
и проблема в том, что если это диалоговое окно появляется то вокруг картинки появляется рамка, потому что картинка круглая, а сама кнопка квадратная. Хотел бы узнать можно ли это исправить каким-то образом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]